# EF6 - updating child objects in a list of parent object causes enumeration error

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I need to update a list of objects which each has a list of child objects. When I try to add the child object to the DB context, I get an error saying "Collection was modified, enumeration operation may not execute". I've tried changing ToList() and this does not help. Here is a sample:

```
public void Update(List<Parent> parents)
{
    // I've made this a FOR loop instead of FOREACH - doesn't help
    for (int i = 0; i < parents.Count; i++)
    {
        var parent = parents[i];
        var dbEntry = _db.Entry(parent);
        dbEntry.State = EntityState.Modified;

        foreach (var child in dbEntry.Entity.Children)
            if (!parent.Children.Exists(ent => ent.Id == child.Id))
                _db.Children.Remove(child);

        foreach (var child in parent.Children)
            if (child.Id == 0)
                dbEntry.Entity.Children.Add(child); <-- ENUMERATION ERROR HERE
    }
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

I've searched everywhere for an answer but cannot figure this one out. Every way I try to fix it just end up with the same result. Any ideas?

Comment: Your issue may not be EF6 related; it could have something to do with `foreach` being a read-only loop... The error you're getting is typical of modifying any collection that is currently being enumerated by a `foreach` operation. Can you use a `for` loop for the inner loops instead?

Comment: @CoolBots I think modifying the collection you're iterating through may actually be an inherently bad idea. OP, you mention using ToList(); where did you use it?

Comment: @Ed Plunkett, I generally agree, just trying to address what might be the immediate cause of OP's error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the look of it, you are trying to add the children to the exact same colleciton you are iterating over in the last foreach.

```
var dbEntry = _db.Entry(parent);
```

therefore

```
parent = dbEntry.Entity
```

The problem is with this foreach

```
foreach (var child in parent.Children)
        if (child.Id == 0)
            dbEntry.Entity.Children.Add(child); <--dbEntry.Entity points to same variable as parent.
```

In the above `foreach`

```
parent.Children == dbEntry.Entity.Children
```

### Change Tracking Options

If you have change tracking enabled and `Parent.Children` property is mapped correctly you don't need to do nothing.

If you disabled automatic change tracking, all you should potentially have to do is:

```
    var dbEntry = _db.Entry(parent);
    dbEntry.State = EntityState.Modified;
```

possibly, you may have to loop over each child and mark it as added, e.g.:

```
foreach (var child in parent.Children)
     if (child.Id == 0) // This is a new Child
         _db.Entry(child).State = EntityState.Added
```

### Observations:

The following `if` statement will always be false!

```
    foreach (var child in dbEntry.Entity.Children)
        if (!parent.Children.Exists(ent => ent.Id == child.Id))
```

If you want to delete children which have since been removed from the list, but you know you definitely requested them without `AsNoTracking()`. Then you should be able to use the `_db.Children.Local` property as this will contain all the entities you've retrieved. But make sure you you check if the child exists in any of the `List<Parents>` otherwise you may be trying to delete a child who has switched parents, e.g. been adopted.

Can you tell me why are you managing this state manually?

Why not let EF track state changes for you? Then you don't need to worry about nothing other than Adding/Removing the actual children somewhere else, and then just calling `_db.SaveChanges()`

Comment: Yes this seems to be correct, can you suggest how to work around this?

Comment: If Michal doesn't answer this I'd suggest you do `parent.Children.ToList()`. BTW, you might as well use `parent.Children.Add(child)`.

Comment: @RickWheeler are you sure you want to be doubling the children in your entities Children collection? If the Children collection is a mapped/navigation property entity, your last for each might be not needed.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on what you are trying to achieve? A small sample object graph of before and after would be usefull

Comment: @GertArnold Question is, why is he trying to remove the Children from the database altogether (1st foreach), and then instead adding a **second** copy of them into a List which already has them in there. Make absolutely no sense

Comment: I think `parents` is an object graph from a disconnected client. OP's code synchronizes the parents in the database with these disconnected entities. If children were removed in the UI, they're removed from the database and if they're new, they're inserted.

Comment: Then in that case there is no need to worry about its children, EF will automatically use the PK to figure out if it's new or modified. If it doesn't all you have to do is set the state to Modified/Added for each child

Comment: No, they need to check if children in the database are in the parent's collection. If they're not, the child in the database must be deleted. Maybe it's not the most efficient way to do it, but a roundtrip to the database can't be avoided.

Comment: During a batch process the children are always deleted before new ones calculated and added, so the old ones need to be deleted from the database. The problem was as indicated in the answer above and I now use the "if (child.Id == 0)" to check for new things being added which is working great. Thanks everyone for your comments and help, it got me out of a very tight deadline last week!